# OSQL.exe is not a valid WIN 32 application

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd, osql

I am trying to compile some indexes using osql.exe command utility (sql server 2008 R2) but getting this error-

### Error:

```
OSQL.Exe is not a valid Win32 application.
```

### Command:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>osql.exe -S 10.42.92.11 -E -d tableA -n -i \\10.32.32.12\L501\\osql\lhpx_addr_exct.sql
```

I also tried to execute the same command with sqlcmd.exe and it executed fine.

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn>sqlcmd.exe -S 10.42.92.11 -E -d tableA -n -i \\10.32.32.12\L501\\osql\lhpx_addr_exct.sql
```

and it executed succesfully.

Please suggest me how to solve osql issue..

Comment: This issue got resolved by using osql in place of osql.exe.

Comment: FYI, osql is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) and you should use sqlcmd instead anyway.